# Woocommerce : Sales Price with scheduling -- default function -- Duplicate possible?

Tags: countdowntimer

Use Case : Computer Retail shop

Regular price  = SRP.

Sales Price (Currently defined) = Permanent Online Customer Price. (I guess I could also replace this with User Role pricing field which only requires Facebook Member and Customer roles for the same pricing tier)

Manager requires another Sales Price field with scheduling to reflect Monthly Adhoc Promo price from Distributors.

Is the above possible?

In addition, if possible add Countdown timer for this new Sales Price field.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi.

Its not a problem perse. More of asking for help to implement the function using coding via Code snippets.

So I do not know what is the coding at all. All i need is a way to add/duplicate the Sales price and scheduling function.

Thanks.

Comment: Or an alternative to achieve what my manager needs. I can perhaps use User role pricing for the permanent member price and use the default Sales price function? But how about the Countdown timer (I just need a simple one).  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Regular price vs Online member price vs Monthly adhoc distributer promotion price